# Tests for Java Map and ConcurrentMap contract

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm working on a custom implementation of Map and ConcurrentMap (with additional features). Are there existing unit tests for the Map and ConcurrentMap contract from the JDK or some libraries that we can borrow?

Comment: Why not just test the additional features independent of the JDK-provided classes?

Comment: That is not enough. My implementation doesn't base on JDK HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap, but it is from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The [jtreg](http://openjdk.java.net/jtreg/) is the regression test suite for the JDK. The tests for the concurrency utilities can be found here:

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/test/jtreg/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap/